# How does Solana prevent forks and orphan blocks due to its speed?

Tags: consensus

Solana is fast, but with speed I'd imagine it would create mini forks or orphan blocks. How does Solana prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trent is correct that this really is a complicated question to answer here. If you have a more focused question, you might get a better response.

As mentioned, Solana does not attempt to stop micro forks from happening. Instead, it tries to ensure that validators are incentivized to correct course when such events happen. And they happen all the time. There isn’t a solution to the Byzantine warriors problem but you can sort of cheat by solving for it in the past. Specifically, validators don’t know they have solved consensus until what they have voted on is in the past.

If you’re looking for a deep dive into the consensus mechanisms, Anatoly has done a few good whiteboard sessions on the topic.

Take a look here:  https://youtu.be/rKGhbC6Uync

Answer (score 0):

This question is really too broad to answer concretely here, but tldr is that it doesn't. Rather it attempts to resolve forks as quickly as possible to reduce their impact on throughput